# Get Token in Json

Tags: c#, .net, json, json.net

I have a problem with this JSON to get the second level in JArray:

```
{
  "Level1": {
    "Level2": [{
      "id": "Chart",
      "Box": [{
        "id": "1",
        "value": "10"
       },{
        "id": "2",
        "value": "20"
       }]
    }]
  }
}
```

And I want to get completly the level 2 like Array in this way:

```
JArray contasdasd = _jsonMaster["Level1"]["Level2"] as JArray;
```

I get :

```
{
  "id": "Chart",
  "Box": [{
    "id": "1",
    "value": "10"
  },{
    "id": "2",
    "value": "20"
  }]
}
```

and I want:

```
"Level2": [{
  "id": "Chart",
  "Box": [{
    "id": "1",
    "value": "10"
  },{
    "id": "2",
    "value": "20"
  }]
}]
```

Is there any way to get the level 2 ?

Comment: so take `['Level2']` out of your _JsonMaster line... if you need that key, then you have to start one level higher up...

Comment: Thanks @Marc B, If I need to use the result to concatenate with another Json file, How can I do that, I can't work with the result..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The object you are interested in `"Level2": [...]` is not a JArray itself but is a `JProperty`.  You can get it by searching properties of `Level1` but keep in mind you will now have a `JProperty` rather than a `JArray`.  The `Value` of that result will be the `JArray` you were getting in your current code.

```
    JProperty contasdasd = _jsonMaster["Level1"].First(o => (o as JProperty).Name == "Level2") as JProperty;

    Console.WriteLine(contasdasd.ToString()); // Will be what you are looking for
    Console.WriteLine(contasdasd.GetType()); // Will return JProperty
    Console.WriteLine(contasdasd.Value.GetType()); // Will return JArray
```

Answer (score 1):

Surely you just do

```
var level1 = _jsonMaster["Level1"];
```

The problem is that you've gone one level too far.

Comment: I was testing this way but the problem was How can I do that: var level1 = _jsonMaster["Level2"];
        var level2 = _jsonApplication["Level2"];, means Merge into one json, with two Level2.

Comment: @JohnKass Sorry, I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I mean.. The problem I have now is the result of this var result = _jsonMaster["Level2"];, because with this result I need to concatenate to another Json, How Can I work with the result for Add this level2 to another Json File?

Comment: @JohnKass Does this post answer your question above, or not. Don't extent it with new requirements.